# Physical meaning of $dx/dt$ for objects of changing length

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics, mathematics

I was solving '[200 Puzzling Problems in Physics](https://catdir.loc.gov/catdir/samples/cam034/00053005.pdf)' as a recreational activity and I encountered this beautiful question which surprised me as I understood a basic flaw in my conceptual understanding.

The problem is the following (but my doubt is on the conceptual side)

> A long, thin, pliable carpet is laid on the floor. One end of the
> carpet is bent back and then pulled backwards with constant unit
> velocity, just above the part of the carpet which is still at rest on
> the floor. Find the speed of the centre of mass of the moving part.

So my doubt is: if a rod of length $x$ is placed on the x-axis say from $(x,0)$ to $(2x,0)$ and its right-most end is pulled with a constant velocity $v$, while writing the differential expression for speed, I ended up writing $dx/dt$ and solved the problem incorrectly.
The reason for me taking $dx/dt$ is because the length of the rod is $x$ and if we displace it slightly by $dx$ for a small time $dt$, then velocity is $dx/dt$.

Later on, checking the solution I realised that the correct way to take the velocity expression is $d(2x)/dt$ which I presume is that we have to consider the length of the end that is being pulled from the origin. However, I really didn't understand why. How is this intuitively different?

Comment: Could you include the question itself? Right now it is hard to tell what the puzzle is about

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion Ok just a sec...Ill edit it. But the me adding the puzzle isn't really any helpful but sure!

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion Please look at the question

Comment: Ah that helps, very interesting puzzle.

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion Just to be clear once more, I did solve the puzzle and dont expect any answer wrt to the particular question. Im just curious about how the mathematical expression makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$dx/dt$ only means velocity when $x$ represents the position of an object. Otherwise it just means the rate of change for a quantity $x(t)$.

You described a scenario that has high chance of confusion. An object which spans from $x(t)$ to $2x(t)$. This describes an object whose left side is located at $x(t)$, whose right side is located at $2x(t)$ and whose length is $x(t)$ (it grows in time!). So what does $v=x'(t)$ describe? It *does* describe the velocity of the left side. It also describes the rate at which your object grows. It does not describe the velocity of the center of mass. To get the center of mass, you should take the mean of the left and the right side (assuming your object has constant density). This gives $x_\text{COM}(t)=\tfrac 1 2(x(t)+2x(t))=1.5x(t)$.

What is now the velocity of the center of mass? Just take the derivative to get

$$v_\text{COM}=\frac{d}{dt}x_\text{COM}(t)=1.5x'(t)=1.5v$$

---

Note: in the question we have $x'(t)=\tfrac 1 2 v$. I stuck with $x'(t)=v$ because it avoids confusion in answering the main question. If you pick $x'(t)=\tfrac 1 2 v$ you will get $v_\text{COM}=\tfrac 3 4v$.

Comment: Great Answer! I appreciate your expln of my doubt...however your final result of computation of the problem is incorrect which I assume is probably due to a careless...Ill edit it. Thanks brother by the way!

Comment: Note that your $v$ here is not the velocity mentioned in the problem, it is half of it

Comment: @BioPhysicist Good catch, I was focussing on the part below the problem so I picked $v=x'(t)$ for clarity

Comment: I feel so stupid I was trying the problem myself and I didn't read that the COM should 
*only* be of the moving part. I'm now pretty sure that the COM of the carpet is given by $x_\text{COM}=\frac{t^2 v^2}{4 L}-\frac{L}{2}$ and $v_\text{COM}=\frac{t v^2}{2 L}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $v$ be the velocity with which the edge of the carpet is pulled.
Then the fold is moving with velocity $\frac 12 v$.
So the CoM of the moving part of the carpet has velocity $\frac 34 v$.

You can use calculus notation if you like:  $v_{CoM}=\frac d{dt}\frac 12\left(vt+\tfrac 12 vt\right)$.

Note that the fold is moving relative to the material of the carpet, as is the CoM of the moving part.

Comment: I know that an answer to the carpet question wasn't asked for, but I thought it might help with the conceptual issue. I'm afraid that I couldn't understand the stuff about rods.

Comment: At t=0 the folded part of the carpet goes from x=0 to x=0 (its length is zero). Now pull the carpet in the positive x direction as explained in the question: at time t>0, the folded part of the carpet goes from x=x(t) to x=2x(t).